# Alternating group with special form

Tags: abstract-algebra

We have defined the group $A_{n}$ to be the group of the even permutations. By theorem we know that every even permutation can be written as the product of finitely many 3-cycles. I want to prove that each element of $A_{n}$ can be written as finitely many 3-cycles of the form (1 2 i), where 2<=i<=n. 
Now, if we prove that (a b)(c d) can be written in finitely many 3-cycles, we are done. 
Case 1. a=c,b=d. Then we have: (a b)(a b)=(1), so we can write it as the product of zero 3-cycles of the form (1 2 i)

Case 2. We set a=c and b not equal to d. Then we have (a b)(a d)=(a d b)

How can I write (a b)(a d) as the product of finitely many 3-cycles of the form (1 2 i)? 
When I have proven case 2, for case 3 I take a not equal to c, b not equal to d. Then we have (a b)(c d)=(a b)(a c) (c a)(cd)=(a c b) (c d a). So if I have case two I have case 3 and I am done, but I dont know how to prove case 2.

Can someone help me with that?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

How about $(ab)(ad)=(adb)=(12d)(12d)(12b)(12b)(12a)(12a)(12b)(12d)$?

Comment: Is there a structured way to come to this solution you just gave? Because this solution is almost impossible to think of without a tactic or some sort(from my view)

Comment: Honestly I just tinkered and got it to work.  Fine question though.